# Отдельная страница с изображением

Tags: php

Есть php код галереи, в нем адрес картинки берется из бд. Мне нужно создать отдельную страницу с картинкой(на ней в дальнейшем будут комменты и количество просмотров). Не могу понять как сопоставить клик со страницы галереи с переходом на уже другую страницу - страницу картинки (как на полной странице сделать ту же картинку по которой кликнули)

```
        <div class='col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3'>
            <a class="thumbnail" rel="" href="uploads/<?php echo $image['image']?>" target="_blank">
                <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="uploads/<?php echo $image['image'] ?>" />
                <div class='text-center'>
                    <small class='text-muted'><?php echo $image['title'] ?></small>
                    <p class='text-muted'>Размер: <?php echo $image['size'] ?></p>
                    <p class='text-muted'>Адрес: <?php echo $image['address'] ?></p>
                </div> <!-- text-center / end -->
            </a>
        </div> <!-- col-6 / end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

В базе данных наверняка должен быть какой-нибудь идентификатор (ID) - подставляйте его, а при переходе проверяйте существует ли картинка, есть ли доступ к ней, etc.

Comment: а как сопоставить одинаковые id на разных страницах?

Comment: Ну так по логике id должен браться из базы данных. если ид уникальный (а он и должен быть уникальным) - выполняйте поиск по базе данных, находите нужное изображение и работайте. Вам всё равно придётся привязывать комментарии к изображениям, поэтому уникальный идентификатор должен быть.